# Why does ActiveReports 2 Drawline only draw on last page?

Tags: vb6, activereports

I am working on a legacy VB6 application that uses ActiveReports 2. I am experimenting with drawing lines on the page. When I have a report where the data causes the generated report to have more than one page, I noticed that the DrawLine method only draws the line on the last page.

For example, in the ReportEnd event handler of the ActiveReport, I have the following code:

```
Me.Pages(0).DrawLine 2000, 2000, 2000, 5000
Me.Pages(1).DrawLine 2000, 2000, 2000, 5000
```

When I have a two page report, the line only appears on page 2. Does anybody know why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I should use the PageEnd event handler instead with the following code:

```
Me.Canvas.DrawLine 2000, 2000, 2000, 5000
```

This will draw a line on each page after it is rendered.

Comment: Indeed, PageEnd is usually the right place for drawing code if you want it to appear on top. If you want it to appear below the report content, use PageStart. You should mark this answer as the correct answer to your question (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).